Understanding the example when $\int f = \infty.$
I was reading the following problem in folland and I am not quite sure how to give an example of the second part of it:
Suppose $\{f_n\} \subset L^+, f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $\int f = \lim \int f_n < \infty.$ Then $$\int_E f = \lim \int_E f_n$$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}.$ However, this need not be true if $$\int f = \lim \int f_n = \infty.$$
Can anyone clarify this example to me please?

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $f_n\colon \mathbb{R}\to[0,+\infty]$ as
$$
f_n := \chi_{(-\infty,0)} + \chi_{[n,n+1]}\ \ ,
$$
in which $\chi$ denotes an indicator function.
Note that for every $n$, the value of $f_n$ is constantly $1$ for negative input values, and $0$ for positive input values except those in the interval $[n,n+1]$. Regardless of $n$, the graph of $f_n$ looks the same on the left-half of the input axis -- a flat (half) line raised $1$ unit above zero -- but on the right half, the graph changes with $n$: The (positive) interval on which the graph is non-zero keeps hopping to the right as $n$ increases. This is usually referred to as "escape to infinity".
The pointwise limit of $f_n$ is $f=\chi_{(-\infty,0)}$. In other words, the graph of $f$ lacks that hopping portion $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ on the positive inputs. That hopping portion's contribution to $\int f_n$ is negligible compared to the contribution of $\chi_{(-\infty,0)}$.
Clearly, regardless of $n$, the area under $f_n$ is $+\infty$. So, limit of the constant area is infinity too.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\ =\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int\chi_{(-\infty,0)}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \chi_{[n,n+1]}\ = +\infty\ \ ,
$$
which is equal to the area under $f$ because
$$
\int f\ =\ \int\chi_{(-\infty,0)}\ =\ +\infty\ \ .
$$
However, on $E=[0,+\infty)$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n\ =\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E \chi_{[n,n+1]}\ =\ 1\ \ .
$$
which is clearly not equal to
$$
\int_E f\ =\ 0\ \ .
$$
In short,
$$
\int f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n = +\infty\quad\land\quad \int_E f \ne \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n \ \ .
$$
